# How to write OR condition in Select Query

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

Is there  a way in mysql  to express 'OR' ?  The idea is to search if there is a match `"user.getinput()"`  that corresponds  to the `username` column or the `email` column. How to express this in a proper way.

```
SELECT  FROM tablex WHERE username OR email = '"+ user.getinput()+"'";
```

Comment: `username = ? OR email = ?` and use a prepared statement with proper SQL parameters

Answer (score 3):

The following is the query:

```
SELECT  FROM tablex WHERE username = ? OR email = ?
```

Better use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

```
String query = "SELECT  FROM tablex WHERE username = ? OR email = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);  
stmt.setString(1,userName);
stmt.setString(2,email);  

stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: My Bad! Updated the same

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use a prepared statement to prevent sql injection issues.

Something like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
     "SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
stmt.setParameter(1, "something");
stmt.setParamater(2, "something");
```